# Merging two tables together / one on top of the other

Tags: tables

I am having a little trouble with trying to "merge" two latex tables together. What I would like is something like the following:

[image]

If possible with a tiny "gap" between the 2015 / 2016 data (between "Support" and "Precision" instead of one full straight line.

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{some caption}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.10\textwidth}p{0.10\textwidth}p{0.10\textwidth}p{0.10\textwidth}p{0.10\textwidth}p{0.10\textwidth}p{0.10\textwidth}p{0.10\textwidth}p{0.10\textwidth}p{0.10\textwidth}} \\ \toprule

    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{2015} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{2016} \\ \midrule
    &  Precision & Recall & F1 & Support &  Precision & Recall & F1 & Support\\ \midrule
    Negative &  &  & &  & -&-&-&- \\
    Neutral & &  & &  &-&-&-&- \\
    Growth &  &  &  &  &-&-&-&- \\ \\
    Accuracy & & &  &  &&&& \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The table will be populated with numbers such as `0.50`, `0.27` etc. and not long text.

EDIT: Here is all the packages I am using in the document (I think the above table uses the booktabs package):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}

\usepackage{graphicx} %Loading the package
\graphicspath{{graphics/}} %Setting the graphicspath
```

Comment: Could you please add teh documentclass as well as the *relevant*  packages? Unrelated to the question: You define 10 columns but only seem to use 9 of them.

Comment: Regarding the line: `\cmidrule` instead of `\midrule` might be interesting.

Comment: I added all the packages I use in the document. Are you saying that `\cmidrule` is a better option the `\midrule`?

Comment: `\cmidrule` is not generally better than `\midrule`. The former offers the possibility to draw a horizotnal line that spans only some columns instead of the whole table. With that, you can create a visual gap between the 2015 and the 2016 block of data as shown in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and thanks for your solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following MWE, I have replaced the `\midrule` by two `\cmirule`s and also replaced `p` type columns by `l` typ columns.

If you are also interested in aligning the numbers that you mentioned in your question, you might want to take a look at the `siunitx` package and its `S` type columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{some caption}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lllllllll}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{2015} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{2016} \\ 
    \cmidrule(r){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9}
    &  Precision & Recall & F1 & Support &  Precision & Recall & F1 & Support\\ \midrule
    Negative &  &  & &  & -&-&-&- \\
    Neutral & &  & &  &-&-&-&- \\
    Growth &  &  &  &  &-&-&-&- \\ \addlinespace
    Accuracy & & &  &  &&&& \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Regarding the "one on top of the other"  from your question, you might also be interested in the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{some caption}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lllllllll}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{2015} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{2016} \\ 
    \cmidrule(r){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9}
    &  Precision & Recall & F1 & Support &  Precision & Recall & F1 & Support\\ \midrule
    Negative &  &  & &  & -&-&-&- \\
    Neutral & &  & &  &-&-&-&- \\
    Growth &  &  &  &  &-&-&-&- \\ \addlinespace
    Accuracy & & &  &  &&&& \\ \midrule
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{2015} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{2016} \\ 
    \cmidrule(r){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9}
    Negative &  &  & &  & -&-&-&- \\
    Neutral & &  & &  &-&-&-&- \\
    Growth &  &  &  &  &-&-&-&- \\ \addlinespace
    Accuracy & & &  &  &&&& \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: exactly what I wanted (actually better than what I had in mind!) thanks!